# How can I test a rabbit's vision?

Tags: rabbits, vision

I'm starting to wonder if my vision on my rabbit is failing. We've had her for 3 years and she seems startled when I come over to her. I'm probably guessing that she doesn't see me at first but when I'm like right in front of her she can see me and she backs up like she's startled. Can we tell if a rabbit's vision is failing? If so, how?

Comment: Has anything happened that might have possibly made the rabbit start to not trust you?

Comment: she actually started running away from me when I try to put her in her cage

Comment: Your assumption of vision being the issue may be mistaken, When you are near her and believe she is unaware of you (directly behind or directly in front) clap your hands and see if she responds.  This will test her hearing, up date you question with the results of the hearing test.

Comment: She has great hearing it was actually tested and she's fine. It's her vision that I'm wondering

Comment: When she backs up, are you walking past her, or reaching out to touch her?

Comment: reaching out to touch her

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure if it works exactly the same but I needed to test the eyesight of my dog for a while because of infection.

What I did was put my finger up and approach it slowly to see if she would react in case she got blind.
As I understood from the vet, every animal would turn away when you get too close to the eye. Doing this with some speed will let you notice when they think it gets too dangerous for them and can help you test eye sight on distance. (never touch the eye though). This will not get a 100% sure result because it will only react when it gets too close in the opinion of the animal.

It might give you a good indication of the eye sight.